# php file renaming virtually wamp environment htaccess

Tags: php, windows, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Does PHP supports htaccess URL rewriting in Windows - WAMP Environment?

How can I use it?

Below is one example:

My existing file name and URL is like below:

```
http://localhost/um/api_user_registration.php?FIRSTNAME=first_name&LASTNAME=last_name&USERNAME=user_name&EMAIL=abc@abc.com
```

Can I use it like below:

```
http://localhost/um/UserRegistration.mac?FIRSTNAME=first_name&LASTNAME=last_name&USERNAME=user_name&EMAIL=abc@abc.com
```

In short, I want to access file as `UserRegistration.mac` instead of `api_user_registration.php`

Please suggest a way of doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL rewriting is done using mod_rewrite, an apache module. Make sure that it's loaded (probably in httpd.conf) and then add this to the htaccess file in your `/um/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /um/
RewriteRule ^UserRegistration\.mac$ api_user_registration.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /yourproject
RewriteRule ^UserRegistration.mac/([^/]+)/(.*)  api_user_registration.php?id=$1 [PT]
```

more info: http://goo.gl/EBzz6t